# localStorage + createContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a context like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const VehicleContext = createContext();

function VehicleContextProvider(props) {
  //Set vehicles array holding drivers objects
  const [photo] = useState(null)
  const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState([
    {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      brand: "Honda",
      model: "Accord",
      prodYear: 2012,
      bodyType: "Sedan",
      registrationNum: "XYZ 98791",
      tankCapacity: 60,
      fuelConsumption: 8,
      fuelType: "Petrol",
      photo:
        photo ||
        "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/carwallet-react.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fhonda.jpg?alt=media&token=dcca1cde-ed10-4004-9ddf-0085e1a9b815",
    },
  ]);

  //Declare function allowing to add vehicles
  const addNewVehicle = (vehicle) => {
    setVehicles([
      ...vehicles,
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        brand: vehicle.brand,
        model: vehicle.model,
        prodYear: vehicle.prodYear,
        bodyType: vehicle.bodyType,
        registrationNum: vehicle.registrationNum,
        tankCapacity: vehicle.tankCapacity,
        fuelConsumption: vehicle.fuelConsumption,
        fuelType: vehicle.fuelType,
        photo: vehicle.photo,
      },
    ]);
  };

  //Declare function to remove certain vehicle form array
  const removeVehicle = (id) => {
    setVehicles(vehicles.filter((vehicle) => vehicle.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <VehicleContext.Provider
      value={{ vehicles, addNewVehicle, removeVehicle }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </VehicleContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default VehicleContextProvider;
```

In my form i get the data from user to add new vehicle object to vehicles array.
Question is: ***can I add these items to user's local storage on submit? if so - how?***

I am using createContext / useContext without useReducer nor Redux.
I've tried useEffect but without success. Data is saved to localStorage, but on reload it is set to initial value given in context.

Answer (score 0):

You can save `vehicles array` to local Storage on `Submit`, like you have explained in your question.

And while initialising data in `useState`, get data from localStorage. If found send the data from it otherwise use initial vehicle data.

```
const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState(() => {
  const localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("vehicles"));
  return (
    localData || [
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        brand: "Honda",
        model: "Accord",
        prodYear: 2012,
        bodyType: "Sedan",
        registrationNum: "XYZ 98791",
        tankCapacity: 60,
        fuelConsumption: 8,
        fuelType: "Petrol",
        photo:
          photo ||
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/carwallet-react.appspot.com/o/photos%2Fhonda.jpg?alt=media&token=dcca1cde-ed10-4004-9ddf-0085e1a9b815",
      },
    ]
  );
});
```